# Hitch solution of Varnish doesn't work

Tags: ssl, reverse-proxy, varnish, varnish-vcl

For now 2 weeks, I've tried to run my hitch with my varnish solution in order to cache my SSL pages.
When I query my pages on port 80 everything works fine, but on port 443, I display a blank page or errors.

[Internet] -----> [Firewall] -----> [Proxy (Hitch + Varnish) -------> [Server web]

This is my schema of the infra.

My hitch conf is:

```
frontend = "[*]:443"
backend = "[127.0.0.1]:80"
pem-file = "/etc/hitch/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.pem"
ciphers = "EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH"
prefer-server-ciphers = off
ssl-engine = ""
workers = 1
backlog = 100
keepalive = 3600
chroot = ""
user = "hitch"
group = "hitch"
quiet = off
syslog = on
syslog-facility = "daemon"
daemon = on
write-ip = off
write-proxy-v1 = on
write-proxy-v2 = off
proxy-proxy = off
sni-nomatch-abort = off
```

My Varnish.params:

```
# Set this to 1 to make systemd reload try to switch VCL without restart.
    RELOAD_VCL=1

# Main configuration file. You probably want to change it.
VARNISH_VCL_CONF=/etc/varnish/default.vcl

# Default address and port to bind to. Blank address means all IPv4
# and IPv6 interfaces, otherwise specify a host name, an IPv4 dotted
# quad, or an IPv6 address in brackets.
VARNISH_LISTEN_ADDRESS=
#VARNISH_LISTEN_ADDRESS=0.0.0.0
VARNISH_LISTEN_PORT=80

# Admin interface listen address and port
VARNISH_ADMIN_LISTEN_ADDRESS=127.0.0.1
VARNISH_ADMIN_LISTEN_PORT=6082

# Shared secret file for admin interface
VARNISH_SECRET_FILE=/etc/varnish/secret

# Backend storage specification, see Storage Types in the varnishd(5)
# man page for details.
VARNISH_STORAGE="malloc,256M"

# User and group for the varnishd worker processes
VARNISH_USER=varnish
VARNISH_GROUP=varnish

# Other options, see the man page varnishd(1)
#DAEMON_OPTS="-p thread_pool_min=5 -p thread_pool_max=500 -p thread_pool_timeout=300"
#DAEMON_OPTS="-a :6081"
```

My netstat -ntap is:

```
    tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9299/varnishd       
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3940/sshd           
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9007/hitch          
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6082          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9298/varnishd       
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:199           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      938/snmpd           
tcp        1      0 10.0.9.192:49032        10.0.9.190:80           CLOSE_WAIT  9299/varnishd        
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      9299/varnishd               
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      9007/hitch
```

Comment: Be specific. What errors you get with SSL?

Comment: I think you need to disable `write-proxy-v1` else to start varnishd with something like `-a <your external address> -a 127.0.0.1,PROXY` ([Varnish supports both versions of PROXY protocol](http://varnish-cache.org/docs/4.1/whats-new/changes.html#proxy-protocol-support) by the way)

Comment: Thank's for your help, my page appears right now, I would not have found without you. Thanks again.

Comment: Re, I've one other questions, when i run hitch i've this message " Warning: Hitch has been compiled against a version of OpenSSL without ALPN support." and when i do "hitch -t" i've "No x509 certificate PEM file specified for frontend 'default'!" Why?

Comment: @Marc-Antoine: You need to add `alpn-protos = "h2, http/1.1"` to your `hitch.conf` file to enable support for ALPN.